# Shorthand for binding jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say, we have a simple form validation code that binds event listeners on multiple input fields:

```
    var self = this,
        name = $("#name") || opts.name,
        surname = $("#surname") opts.surname,
        email = $("#email") || opts.email ,
        phone = $("#phone") || opts.phone;

    name.on('blur change', function() {
        self.validateName(name);
    });
    surname.on('blur change', function() {
        self.validateSurname(surname);
    });
    email.on('blur change', function() {
        self.validateEmail(email);
    });
    phone.on('blur change', function() {
        self.validatePhone(phone);
    });
```

Is there any way to shorten this without losing any performance? For example, if I want to check if some input are exists in the form, there will be too much repetitive if(input) {...} statements.

UPD: ID's (or classes) can be different and function can accept an object with input fields:

```
var validation = new Validation({
    name: $('.name'), 
    surname:..
});
```

Comment: I think you can minimize on the redundancy by making one generic `validate` function that takes in two parameters -- one specifying whether it is a name, surname, email, or phone.

Comment: This was the first thing I did. But then, I realized that specifying a large number of parameters (and forms are big sometimes) is not very effective way of doing this. Surprisingly, many existing JS librarys are doing exactly this. For their own simplicity, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to ids to `Name`, `Surname`, `Email`, `Phone`, then the relevant validator can be determined formulaically :

```
var self = this;
$("#Name, #Surname, #Email, #Phone").on('blur change', function() {
    self['validate' + this.id]($(this));
});
```

**EDIT**

The blur/change handler can be generalized as follows :

```
$("myForm input").on('blur change', function() {
    var fn = self['validate' + this.id];
    if(fn) {
        fn($(this));
    }
});
```

All you then need to do is ensure that all input fields that need validating have

- an appropriate ID
- a corresponding validation function

The `if(fn)` test prevents an error being thrown for any inputs that don't need validating (ie for which there is no validation function).

To cater for any non-inputs you would need to broaden the range of the elements selected by the `$("myForm input")` selector.

Comment: Well, but what if I will have another ID? Or more inputs? Or classes, instead of ID's? 
I will edit my question. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: The second part is helpful. Never seen this kind of self-invoking.
I guess, when dealing with unknown set of element, there must be a way to push the existing ones into single object and then, bind events to all of them at once.

Comment: OK, I've added a bit more to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this... (though in this you need to change the id #inputLname to #inputSurname)

```
    var all = $("#inputFname, #inputLname,  #inputEmail, #inputPhone");

    all.on('blur change', function() {
        var self = this, fnName = validate+self.attr("id").replace("input","");
        self.window[fnName](self);
    });
```

And even `window[]` is pretty quick..